TailwindCSS calc not working when implementing header
I am trying to create a header, below is my implementation of it, I used calc to subtract the height preserved for the header:
<div className='flex flex-col h-full'>
            <Header/> //takes 68px of height
            <div className='absolute h-[calc(100%-68px)] top-[68px] w-full flex'>
                <div className='h-full flex-1' style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(241 245 249)'}} ref={containerRef}>
                    <canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

When inspecting, I see the outer div taking full height of the screen while the div that has h-[calc(100%-68px)] has height of 150px which I don't know where it is from. When I hover on it, it does have the explanation of a typical tailwind class:
.h-\[calc\(100\%-68px\)\] {    
 height: calc(100% - 68px); 
}

Also, here is my Header component:
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className='w-full h-[68px] bg-black absolute z-50'>
            Header
        </div>
    );
};

Using h-full does work, but it is not my intention because the header takes 68px, if I use h-full, it will overflow which I don't want.

I tried your code and it works fine. 150px is the default height of the canvas. Are you sure you didn't inspect the wrong element?

@KarsonJo I'm positive that I inspect the correct element, here is my site if you need more information about the layout.
https://canva-clone-fabricjs.vercel.app/editor/1

Okay, your site does have a 150px height, but I don't see h-[calc(100%-68px)] appearing in the stylesheet. In fact there are a couple other styles that don't appear properly either, like w-full. Is there something wrong with the packing?

@KarsonJo thank you, I see the problem now. It seems like calc is not allowed in tailwind class name styles. Using inline style like
"style={{height: 'calc(100% - 68px)'}}"
solved the problem. What is odd is I code this following a tutorial where they do exactly what I'm doing: using calc in tailwind classname, maybe I missed something?

Without detailed code, it's hard to judge. However, it currently seems to be a Tailwind configuration issue. Many utility classes are not included, so they are not taking effect. Instead, h-full appears to be the only class being picked up... which is why the issue disappears when you change to h-full or use style=.... I suggest checking the tailwind.config.ts file to see if it contains the correct file matching rules.

@KarsonJo yes this is odd, I also looked up calc again and aparently, calc is allowed in tailwind.
I don't see any problem in the tailwind config files, it is the way it is when I first initialized the app and I haven't modify the app's directories.
Maybe I'll initialize another empty app and copy them over to see if the problem resolves.

I took a closer look at your website, and it seems that Tailwind isn't working at all. The only effective h-full class isn't a Tailwind utility class; it looks more like a manually added style. Could there be an issue with the initial Tailwind configuration?

Now that you say it, I noticed that is really the case, the header which I applied bg-black isn't black at all although when I inspect it it says it is #000000 which is black.
About the tailwind config, I don't really know, I haven't touch it since I initialize the app in which tailwind is included when I use npm create-next-app.

I couldn't find any class information using Chrome's debug tools. You said you can inspect it, do you mean in the browser or in VSCode? The IntelliSense from the VSCode plugin doesn't necessarily reflect the actual effect.

@KarsonJo I found out why, I initially create a directory inside src and store components there and I should have added the line "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}" in the tailwind.config.ts which I didn't, this is embarassing.
All good now, thank you very much and sorry for taking your time.

You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.

You let the <Header /> use the space it needs and then set the div to flex-1 to have it use the remaining space available.
<div className='flex flex-col h-full'>
    <Header/> //takes 68px of height
    <div className='flex-1 w-full flex'>
        <div className='h-full flex-1' style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(241 245 249)'}} ref={containerRef}>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


Thank you for your reply.
This doesn't work unfortunately. Also I want the contents area to be scrollable while the header is fixed on top, if I implement like your instruction, I think the header will be scrolled away along with the contents.
